# why do we need an on-the-fly interpreter/assembler to convert code to native machine at run time??

Tags: java, python, operating-system, interpreter, compiler-optimization

Compiler compiles the code before and then interpreter/assembler converts those compiled instructions into native machine instruction on the fly and runs them.
In this process time is consumed by interpreter to convert code to machine language and then run.
Why cant we have offline interpreter which will give us ready to run machine instruction, so that we can have faster programs??
I understand that the memory locations are known at run time only, so we can use some offset in ready-to-run machine

Comment: Are you specifically asking why Java doesn't do this? Because other languages do.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Do you mean other languages keeps native code ready before execution?? And just before execution, processor loads all these native machine instructions(opcodes) into memory to execute them??

Comment: Yes. Although it doesn't usually load them 'just' before execution, but at 'load time'.

Comment: Some compilers go directly to object code without an intervening assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Java was designed to be a cross-platform language. You build the app, you get a Jar. At this point, as you said, you don't have native code. To run your app you execute your jar in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), aaaand that's where all the magic happen. You can take a Jar compiled on Windows and run it on Linux or on MacOs as long as you have a valid JVM installed in your platform.  The JVM will change depending on your platform, your code won't.

Comment: actually you get a class file, not a jar file.

Comment: Your jar contains your class files

Comment: yes, but if you do `javac javafile.java` this will create a class file which you then do `java javafile` to execute. if you want to create a jar file you do something like `jar -cf jarFile.jar javaFile`

Comment: Yes I totally agree, but when i said : "You build the app, you get a jar", I meant you build with an IDE. In my short life every IDE I used created a .jar when I launched a build.

Comment: dont think so. Eclipse doesnt for sure, you need to export it, and Netbeans as far as i remember doesnt either, but havent used that for ages so i am not so sure. But what java does and what IDEs do are not the same. for example eclipse compiles the code when you save, Java doesnt. you need to save and run javac in order to compile.

Comment: This discussion is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: a .jar is just a .zip used to bundle files. The actual program is in the compiled .class

Answer (score 1):

Compiled languages translate your high-level code to the operating system native code, thus, compiled languages are dependent on the environment it will run, such as C, which can be coded from diferent systems, but each will have its own libraries, compilers and builders.

Interpreted translate your high-level code to instructions which an interpreter will execute. The interpreter always accept the same instructions, but eventually, it will have to invoke some native code on the system. Thing is: the same code can be re-used across systems, however since you are not executing native code directly, you end up losing performance, and each system need to implement its own interpreter, such as Python.

Java, on the other hand, is mix of compiled and interpreted. By adding a virtual machine (JVM), java does add another layer between native code and high-level code.
Java code is first compiled into JVM native code. The JVM then interprets this code, and is able to either interpret it as commands and call native code, or to completely compile that code into a native program to be executed. The JVM does an abstraction in the execution process and is able to choose which type of native execution is faster based on the program. Yes, java will always be slower than a pure native code, but it can be much faster than a pure interpreted one, without losing the portability. With the drawback that each system must implement its own JVM (which is really only just a problem for Oracle and other JVM providers).

Answer (score 0):

Consider something simple (and stupid) like this javascript:

```
var x = prompt('Enter some javascript code');
eval(x);
```

To compile this would require that the compiler embed the ENTIRE javascript compiler into the executable, because otherwise `eval()` couldn't work. There's no optimization possible, as the compiler has no idea what the user is going to enter as their JS code-of-choice. Maybe it'll just be `alert('Hi mom!')`, maybe it'll be a 5 million line x86 cpu emulator.

Comment: Yes, javascript compiler will do optimization and will create compiled file, right? now that compiled file have optimized assembly code and now that optimized assembly code need to convert to native language to feed it to processor for execution. This conversion happens on the fly, i.e. while programm is runing, so my question is why cant we keep this converted program ready before execution?

Comment: yes, but that's to optimize about those 2 lines of code? NOTHING. you can't remove anything without changing what the problem does. but since it's using eval(), you necessarily have to have the ENTIRE compiler inside your standalone executable.